How to get correctly sign Solana transaction using PHP Laravel?
I'm using getblock.io as a node for Solana network and I'm trying to sign a transaction and send it through that node in Laravel, but I'm facing a problem with the serialization of the transaction every time I'm getting an error that says :
failed to deserialize solana_sdk::transaction::versioned::VersionedTransaction: io error: failed to fill whole buffer

My code for the transaction signing and sending is below:
public function sendTransaction($privateKey, $recipientAddress, $amount)
    {
        try {
            $client = new Client();
            $rpcUrl = 'https://go.getblock.io/{{MyNodeRpcKey}}/mainnet';

            // Create a transaction
            $transaction = $this->createTransaction($privateKey, $recipientAddress, $amount);

            // Send the transaction
            $response = $client->post($rpcUrl, [
                'json' => [
                    'jsonrpc' => '2.0',
                    'id' => 1,
                    'method' => 'sendTransaction',
                    'params' => [$transaction, ['encoding' => 'base58']]
                ],
                'headers' => [
                    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                ],
            ]);

            $body = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);

            dd($body);

            if (isset($body['result'])) {
                return $body['result']; // Transaction signature
            }

            return null;

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return [$e->getMessage()];
        }
    }

    private function createTransaction($privateKey, $recipientAddress, $amount)
    {
        $recentBlockhash = $this->getRecentBlockhash();
        $publicKey = $this->getPublicKeyFromPrivateKey($privateKey);
        
        $base58 = new Base58();

        // Constructing the transaction
        $transaction = [
            'recentBlockhash' => $recentBlockhash,
            'header' => [
                'numRequiredSignatures' => 1,
                'numReadonlySignedAccounts' => 0,
                'numReadonlyUnsignedAccounts' => 1,
            ],
            'accountKeys' => [
                $base58->encode($publicKey),
                $base58->encode($recipientAddress),
                '11111111111111111111111111111111',
            ],
            'instructions' => [
                [
                    'accounts' => [0, 1],
                    'keys' => [
                        ['pubkey' => $publicKey, 'isSigner' => true, 'isWritable' => true],
                        ['pubkey' => $recipientAddress, 'isSigner' => false, 'isWritable' => true],
                    ],
                    'programId' => '11111111111111111111111111111111', // System program ID
                    'programIdIndex' => 2,
                    "stackHeight" => null,
                    'data' => $base58->encode(pack('P', $amount * 1000000000)) // Convert amount to lamports
                ]
            ],
            'signatures' => [] // Add signatures after signing the transaction
        ];

        
        $signedTransaction = $this->signTransaction($transaction, $privateKey);

        // Serialize transaction
        return $signedTransaction;
    }

    private function getRecentBlockhash()
    {
        $client = new Client();
        $rpcUrl = 'https://go.getblock.io/{{MyNodeRpcKey}}/mainnet';
        $response = $client->post($rpcUrl, [
            'json' => [
                'jsonrpc' => '2.0',
                'id' => 1,
                'method' => 'getRecentBlockhash',
            ],
            'headers' => [
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            ],
        ]);

        $body = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
        return $body['result']['value']['blockhash'] ?? null;
    }

    public function signTransaction(array $transaction, string $privateKeyHex): string
    {
        try {
            // Decode the hex-encoded private key
            $fullPrivateKey = hex2bin($privateKeyHex);
            if ($fullPrivateKey === false) {
                throw new \Exception('Invalid private key format');
            }

            // Extract the private key part
            $privateKey = substr($fullPrivateKey, 0, 32);

            // Serialize the transaction into a byte array
            $transactionBytes = $this->serializeTransaction($transaction);

            // Sign the transaction bytes with the private key
            $signature = Ed25519::sign_detached($transactionBytes, $privateKey);

            // Combine the signature and the transaction
            $signedTransaction = $signature . $transactionBytes;

            // Base64 encode the signed transaction
            return (new Base58())->encode($signedTransaction);
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            return $th->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function serializeTransaction(array $transaction): string
    {
        $serialized = '';
    
        // Serialize header
        $serialized .= chr($transaction['header']['numRequiredSignatures']);
        $serialized .= chr($transaction['header']['numReadonlySignedAccounts']);
        $serialized .= chr($transaction['header']['numReadonlyUnsignedAccounts']);
    
        // Serialize account keys
        foreach ($transaction['accountKeys'] as $accountKey) {
            $serialized .= (new Base58())->decode($accountKey); // Decode from Base58
        }
    
        // Serialize recent blockhash
        $serialized .= (new Base58())->decode($transaction['recentBlockhash']); // Decode from Base58
    
        // Serialize instructions
        $serialized .= $this->serializeCompactU16(count($transaction['instructions']));
        foreach ($transaction['instructions'] as $instruction) {
            $serialized .= $this->serializeInstruction($instruction);
        }
    
        return $serialized;
    }
    
    private function serializeCompactU16(int $value): string
    {
        $buf = '';
        while ($value > 0) {
            $byte = $value & 0x7f;
            $value >>= 7;
            if ($value > 0) {
                $byte |= 0x80;
            }
            $buf .= chr($byte);
        }
        return $buf;
    }
    
    private function serializeInstruction(array $instruction): string
    {
        $serialized = '';
        $serialized .= chr($instruction['programIdIndex']);
        $serialized .= $this->serializeCompactU16(count($instruction['accounts']));
        foreach ($instruction['accounts'] as $account) {
            $serialized .= chr($account);
        }
        $dataLength = strlen((new Base58())->decode($instruction['data']));
        $serialized .= $this->serializeCompactU16($dataLength);
        $serialized .= (new Base58())->decode($instruction['data']); // Decode from Base64
    
        return $serialized;
    }

    public function getPublicKeyFromPrivateKey(string $privateKeyHex)
    {
        try {
            // Decode the hex-encoded private key
            $fullPrivateKey = hex2bin($privateKeyHex);
            if ($fullPrivateKey === false) {
                throw new \Exception('Invalid private key format');
            }

            // Extract the private key part (first 32 bytes)
            $privateKey = substr($fullPrivateKey, 0, 32);

            // Generate the public key from the private key
            $publicKey = Ed25519::publickey_from_secretkey($privateKey);

            return bin2hex($publicKey);
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            return $th->getMessage();
        }
    }

I'm expecting the transaction to go through without a serialization error

sorry that this isn't helping you figure out the issue, but would you mind telling me what library/class you are using to perform your base58 encode/decode functions?
